# SCP restringir el uso de AMIs por ID - AWS

Tags: aws

Quiero restringir el uso de AMIs en instancias ec2 a sólo unas AMIs concretas.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireApprovedAMIType",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:RebootInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:::instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "ec2:ImageType": [
            "ami-0*",
            "ami-0*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Creo que el problema está en el ec2:imagetype pero no consigo encontrar otro que tenga sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Para restringir el uso de AMIs, el recurso debe tener una forma tal que:

```
arn:aws:ec2:*::image-ami-*
```

Si conoces el ARN de las AMIs basta con indicarlas:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:REGION::image/ami-00001",
    "arn:aws:ec2:REGION::image/ami-00002",
    ...
]
```

La condición la podrías usar para, por ejemplo, restringir el uso de AMIs por etiquetas (si fuese tu caso):

```
"Condition": {
     "StringEquals": {
        "ec2:ResourceTag/NOMBRE_TAG": "VALOR_TAG"
     }
  }
```

Comment: Pongo las condiciones porque la política es Deny.

{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "RequireApprovedAMIType",
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Action": [
    "ec2:RunInstances",
    "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
    "ec2:StartInstances",
    "ec2:RebootInstances"
   ],
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:::image-ami-"
   ],
   "Condition": {
    "ArnNotLike": {
     "aws:SourceArn": [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-0xxxxxxx",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-0xxxxxxx"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}